# How to add items into Listbox using ActiveX params?

Tags: delphi, activex

I am new with ActiveX.  I am trying to add some items into a Listbox using HTML params:

```
<object classid="clsid:B8F86405-G7YB-4BDF-AD70-55B265068G44" codebase="project.ocx" width="600" height="500">

  <param name="item" value="item1">
  <param name="item1 id " value="1">
</object>
```

I don't know yet how to do it inside Delphi to read those HTML values.  I think I have to use some getter/setter, but I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Are you prepared for your html pages to be limited to IE? Do you really need ActiveX in a web page?v

Comment: why  i limited  to ie only  , i know active x will not work on  other Netscape browsers , but always there is a way like doing netscape plugin for my activex

Comment: We realised about 15 years ago, perhaps more, that ActiveX had no place in the browser. I guess you didn't see the memo. ;-) Use a modern standards based approach to whatever your problem is.

Comment: i know activex is dead :( , but you know its only way to run my application through web browser , do you suggest other way to run my application in webbrowser with delphi ?

Comment: That's a different question

Comment: @DelphiStudent: Since you are aware of the fact that it will only run in IE and it seems not to be an issue for you: Have you asked yourself what you need the browser for at all? Have you considered to run it simply without any browser, like any other program?

Comment: i already make  a dll plugin and already my application runs on many browsers IE - chrome - safari i just want to know  David suggestion , by the way  i maked my activex throgh all browser using `Netscape Plugin Delphi Framework` my only issues is adding some staff from browser to my application , i think its something about `ActiveXParamList` but i did not  get the whole equation yet .

Comment: yes activex can be run on different browsers - firefox - safari - chrome , but what are you try to achieve ? if you already make  yours , I don't get the point of how to add  values from params to  your activex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML `<object>` element loads parameter values into an ActiveX object using the [`IPersistPropertyBag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768205.aspx) and [`IPropertyBag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/(v=vs.85).aspx) interfaces.  The HTML host (such as a web browser) creates the specified object, and if successful then queries it for `IPersistPropertyBag`, and if successful then calls [`Load()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768206.aspx) passing it an `IPropertyBag` object that the object can [`Read()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768197.aspx) values from as needed.

In Delphi, you do not need to resort to that level.  You can just set the properties directly instead:

```
uses
  ..., ComObj;

var
  Obj: Variant;
begin
  // if you have a ProgID name, use CreateOleObject() instead...
  //Obj := CreateOleObject('progid');
  Obj := CreateComObject(StringToGUID('{B8F86405-G7YB-4BDF-AD70-55B265068G44}'));
  Obj.item := 'item1';
  Obj.item1 := '1';
end;
```

Of course, if the properties are not strings, use the appropriate types.  For example, if `item1` were an integer:

```
Obj.item1 := 1;
```